# Django app as REST-based service

Tags: django, api, rest

According to the documentation, an app is a module which deals a well defined operation.

Is it correct to think about an app as a REST-based service? or is it mandatory to use some framework like piston or tastypie to create a RESTful web service around an app?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, no. Django app is really just a python module, with some interfaces to django internals like models, urls, admin discovery etc.

To implement REST, you still have to manage network communications via views, and this is where you either write your own code or use the help of tastypie/piston/etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please do have a look at django-rest-framework, I just stepped over from tastypie to this new framework, works great!

http://django-rest-framework.org/

Especially the class based views and the browsable api! and may other advantages (e..g. to upload images)

And to answer your question:
The rest-base service is an extra entry to your webapp.
I made some api's for some projects using the django-rest-framework, most project members were surprised they got a webapp as an extra, while it was actually the other way around. You make a django app (with views models and urls) and on top off that you make the api.